# Why isn't my bootstrap request being sent to the server after refreshing the landing page?

Tags: elm

The breakpoint on the local server is triggered only once regardless of the page refreshes.

```
main =
    Navigation.program UrlChange
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
        }

init : Navigation.Location -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init location =
    ( { currentRoute = location
      , ...
      }
    , runtime.bootstrap BootstrapResponse
    )
```

The Explore History window reports that only one message was generated after a page refresh:

```
BootstrapResponse Ok
```

**Question:**

Why isn't my bootstrap request being sent to the server after refreshing the landing page?

**Appendix:**

```
bootstrap : (Result Http.Error JsonBootstrap -> msg) -> Cmd msg
bootstrap msg =
    let
        url =
            baseUrl ++ "bootstrap"

        request =
            Http.get url bootstrapDecoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

**Update:**

I tested this on both Chrome and Edge.

[image]

Comment: What cache headers are your server writing?

Comment: What's your evidence that it isn't being sent to the server? Elm seems to be saying that it is going to the server, and getting back "Ok".

Comment: @ChadGilbert - I attached a screenshot. The headers tab is empty.